# How to rewrite everything to HTTPS except for port

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-rewrite

I installed Netdata on a webserver to get statistics. To see those I should use: **http**://whatever:**19999**. However, everything gets redirected to HTTPS on my webserver using:

```
 RewriteEngine On  
 RewriteRule .*   https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Any elegant way of making sure anything directed at port 19999 will go to HTTP? (and not get redirected again and again to HTTPS ..)
 I guess it can be done by having some condition come before the show RewriteRule, right? but how? The man page on rewriterules just confuses me so any help is welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use add this code to redirect all services that use a specific port to use HTTP instead of HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 19999 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You can also use this code to filter other ports as well:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !19999
```

which will run the next code for all webpages that don't use the 19999 port.

Comment: That sure looks like an elegant solution, way better than the stuff I thought would work. I'll validate your answer as soon as I get control back of my system (stupid me forgot to exclude myself from Fail2Ban jails, whoops).

Comment: Checked and .. it works !

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Redirect](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm aware of that solution, however since my system evolved from having only an IP (which I don't know how to incorporate in a vhost) to having a domain name, I kept the syntax as shown in my post. But cool to be reminded of this possibility to always redirect to HTTPS.

Comment: Your welcome. I hope you find a `Rewrite` solution that suits you. =)